# How to replace numbers with order in (python) list

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, sorting

I have a list containing integers and want to replace them so that the element which previously contained the highest number now contains a 1, the second highest number set to 2, etc etc.

Example:
`[5, 6, 34, 1, 9, 3]` should yield `[4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 5]`.

I personally only care about the first 9 highest numbers by I thought there might be a simple algorithm or possibly even a python function to do take care of this task?

Edit: I don't care how duplicates are handled.

Comment: Can you please provide the snippet of the code you tried.

Comment: What if two numbers are the same?

Comment: `tmp = sorted(input); output = [0] * len(input); for i in range(min(len(tmp), 9)): output[input.index(tmp[i])] = i` was what I thought of but I haven't tested that yet. Also this handles duplicates badly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fast way to do this is to first generate a list of tuples of the element and its position:

```
sort_data = [(x,i) for i,x in enumerate(data)]
```

next we sort these elements in `reverse`:

```
sort_data = sorted(sort_data,reverse=True)
```

which generates (for your sample input):

```
>>> sort_data
[(34, 2), (9, 4), (6, 1), (5, 0), (3, 5), (1, 3)]
```

and nest we need to fill in these elements like:

```
result = [0]*len(data)
for i,(_,idx) in enumerate(sort_data,1):
    result[idx] = i
```

Or putting it together:

```
def obtain_rank(data):
    sort_data = [(x,i) for i,x in enumerate(data)]
    sort_data = sorted(sort_data,reverse=True)
    result = [0]*len(data)
    for i,(_,idx) in enumerate(sort_data,1):
        result[idx] = i
    return result
```

this approach works in *O(n log n)* with *n* the number of elements in `data`.

A more compact algorithm (in the sense that no tuples are constructed for the sorting) is:

```
def obtain_rank(data):
    sort_data = sorted(range(len(data)),key=lambda i:data[i],reverse=True)
    result = [0]*len(data)
    for i,idx in enumerate(sort_data,1):
        result[idx] = i
    return result
```

Comment: @Rawing: it is used to store the original position of the elements. Ev.Kounis algorithm is more elegant, but runs in *O(n^2 log n)* whereas this runs in *O(n log n)*.

Answer (score 4):

Another option, you can use [rankdata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) function from `scipy`, and it provides options to handle duplicates:

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

lst = [5, 6, 34, 1, 9, 3]
rankdata(list(map(lambda x: -x, lst)), method='ordinal')
# array([4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 5])
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuimg you do not have any duplicates, the following list comprehension will do:

```
lst = [5, 6, 34, 1, 9, 3]
tmp_sorted = sorted(lst, reverse=True)  # kudos to @Wondercricket
res = [tmp_sorted.index(x) + 1 for x in lst]  # [4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 5]
```

To understand how it works, you can break it up into pieces like so:

```
lst = [5, 6, 34, 1, 9, 3]
# let's see what the sorted returns
print(sorted(lst, reverse=True))  # [34, 9, 6, 5, 3, 1]
# biggest to smallest. that is handy.
# Since it returns a list, i can index it. Let's try with 6
print(sorted(lst, reverse=True).index(6))  # 2
# oh, python is 0-index, let's add 1
print(sorted(lst, reverse=True).index(6) + 1)  # 3
# that's more like it. now the same for all elements of original list

for x in lst:
    print(sorted(lst, reverse=True).index(x) + 1)  # 4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 5

# too verbose and not a list yet..
res = [sorted(lst, reverse=True).index(x) + 1 for x in lst]
# but now we are sorting in every iteration... let's store the sorted one instead
tmp_sorted = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
res = [tmp_sorted.index(x) + 1 for x in lst]
```

Comment: It would be better to sort *before* list comprehension. As it stands, it is sorting `lst` through every iteration. [repl.it](https://repl.it/GCkv) for performance difference

Comment: Furthermore `index(..)` runs in *O(n)* making this a *O(n^2 log n)* algorithm.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am not so good at calculating complexity. How did you derive that? Is it not just O(n^2) if `index` runs in O(n)?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: now it runs indeed in *O(n^2)* (because the sorting step is only done once). Since `index` runs in *O(n)* and you do this *O(n)* times.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh I see. Thanks.

Comment: Ok that explanation is way more detailed than I need but thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

> `numpy.argsort` returns the indices that would sort an array.

---

```
>>> xs = [5, 6, 34, 1, 9, 3]

>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.argsort(np.argsort(-np.array(xs))) + 1
array([4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 5])
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this, what does -np.array() do, and why the +1?

Comment: `np.array(xs)` create an numpy array. `-np.array(xs)` returns a new array all item negated.

Answer (score 0):

A short, log-linear solution using pure Python, and no look-up tables.

The idea: store the positions in a list of pairs, then sort the list to reorder the positions.

```
enum1 = lambda seq: enumerate(seq, start=1)  # We want 1-based positions

def replaceWithRank(xs):
    # pos = position in the original list, rank = position in the top-down sorted list.
    vp = sorted([(value, pos) for (pos, value) in enum1(xs)], reverse=True)
    pr = sorted([(pos, rank) for (rank, (_, pos)) in enum1(vp)])
    return [rank for (_, rank) in pr]

assert replaceWithRank([5, 6, 34, 1, 9, 3]) == [4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 5]
```